# Backup/Restore which content database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, content-database

I have seen a few posts about backing and restoring SharePoint content databases from both Central Admin and using PowerShell.  My question is relatively simple I hope.....

There are a number of databases on my SharePoint instance I understand.  Two of which are WSS_Content and WSS_Content{xxx-xxx-xxx}(GUID)

Would it suffice to back up these databases 'only' or just one of them to recover a full server farm either in PowerShell or from Central Admin?

There are maintenance tasks running on the server and also Farm backups carried out but in the interest of saving disk space and speed of recovery and overall quality is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WSS_Content** and **WSS_Content{xxx-xxx-xxx}(GUID)** may refer to two different content databases in your farm. Depending on how they are configured they may belong to two site collections in a single web application or two different web applications. Moreover, for a full farm backup, you may need to back up other databases, most importantly the config database and service application databases.

Comment: Thank you.  To clarify there is only a single web application with a single site collection up to now.

Comment: So, where do you want to restore the content database. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Say user X deletes a library from a sub site or generally breaks something.  Or the wrong sub site gets deleted (I don't issue permissions policy, just set them as told), then restoring the content database is a simple possible fix as opposed to restoring farm/granular backups?  Sorry I've been issued this platform as my primary work stream.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can take regular backups of content  database and restore it when needed.

Comment: Thank @Nadeem.  Taking into account my scenario - do I need both content database backing up?  Or can I get away with just the larger of the two?  The one with the GUID?

Comment: You mentioned earlier that you have only one site collection. A site collection cannot have more than one content database. You need to check which of the two content databases is being used by the site collection and restore that one. You can check that by going into Central admin site and click on Manage Content Databases. On Top right change the site collections and see which database is being used by what site.